# OpenLayers select features with Line

Tags: openlayers, postgis

I am trying to select features (Roads and Streets) on layer using **DrawFeature**. I am using Polygon and Line draw options. I got the idea how to select features within polygon from this link and working fine for me

[OpenLayers select features with polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15358561/openlayers-select-features-with-polygon)

when i draw a line it returns me intersected features (Roads and Streets). I want to get feautres which i are completely under the line.

**Actual Map:**

[image]

Here is output which returns **LINESTRING** from **openlayers**.

Red Lines shows the selected roads and street.

I have used the **intersects** function of openlayers.

[image]

I want to get following output

[image]

I have also tried the POSTGIS by getting the **LINESTRING geometry** of Black Line from openlayers.

```
LINESTRING(-15999.270647679 6714225.9041112,-16582.102988273 6714070.6413976)
```

I have used these functions ST_DWithin, ST_Intersects

```
SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(distinct id), ',') 
FROM streets  
WHERE  st_dwithin(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-15999.270647679 6714225.9041112,-16582.102988273 6714070.6413976)',900913),st_transform(geometry, 900913),0);
```

and

```
SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(distinct id), ',') 
FROM streets  
WHERE  st_intersects(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-15999.270647679 6714225.9041112,-16582.102988273 6714070.6413976)',900913),st_transform(geometry, 900913));
```

So Now my question how can I get the roads and streets which are under the black line?

I am finding solution in openlayers or postgis. openlayers can provide me line geometry so i can directly query from database.

Comment: Your question isn't totally clear. What do you mean by the features that are completely inside the line? Also, do you want an OpenLayers or a Postgis solution, as they really are very different.

Comment: I have updated the question please check. features mean roads or streets. I want to select road or street on a map. thank you

Comment: So, you want to create a line that connects the points of other lines, which intersect a line? Do you want to do this in Postgis or OpenLayers?

Comment: Yeah, I have done this in 2nd image you can see. black line is created by drawfeature and i got the linestring as a geometry from this line. now i want to select or get those roads which are under this black line.